# Is a shift operator always linear?

Tags: operator-theory, recurrence-relations

Let $S$ be a shift operator acting on the index of sequences $a_n$ in the sense $Sa_n=a_{n+1}$.

I have two questions regarding this definition.

1. Can $S$ be properly defined to have this property acting on ANY sequence, or is its definition bound to a particular sequence?
2. Is $S$ always a linear operator?

My thought's on it:

Let's define a sequence
$$a_{2n}=a_n+a_{n-1} \\
a_{2n+1}=a_n-a_{n-1}.$$ Now let $S$ be universal in the sense of 1) and furthermore let $S$ to have the property as in 2) (so it is linear). Since $S$ is linear, we have
$$Sa_{2n}=S\left(a_n+a_{n-1}\right) \\
a_{2n+1} =a_{n+1}+a_n  = a_{2n+2}$$
but also
$$Sa_{2n+1}=S\left(a_n-a_{n-1}\right) \\
a_{2n+2}=a_{n+1}-a_n=a_{2n+3}$$
which seems to me as a contradiction, because why - in general - should we have $a_{2n+1}=a_{2n+2}$? In particular, using the equality of the last two equations, we find
$$a_{2n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n=a_{n+1}-a_n \, ,$$
which means $a_n=0$ for all $n$.

So for this $S$ it doesn't seem to be linear, because there seems to exist a non-trivial solution to the defintion of the sequence. At the same time, since $S$ is universal, you could do the same thing on a sequence where the linearity would work out.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  You've defined a map that takes sequences to sequences.  Now, if you had, say, sequences of elements of a field $\mathbb F$ in mind, then the set of sequences over $\mathbb F$ make a vector space over $\mathbb F$, and it is easy to check that the shift is linear.  Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: I don't understand what your example is meant to represent.  You haven't defined a sequence....you've only said something about $a_{2n}$ and nothing about $a_{2n+1}$.  And linearity surely means linear as a map from $\mathbb {Seq}\to \mathbb {Seq}$, it's not defined on individual elements.

Comment: Yes, but at the same time, $a_{2n}$ depends on the odd indices as well. Is my sequence not even properly defined?

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant.  What sequence have you defined?  What is $a_{37}$?

Comment: I updated my example.

Comment: But again, $S$ is defined on Sequences, not on individual terms.  $S$ of your sequence is literally the same sequence, meaning the same set of terms, just shifted over (and note that the first term is cut off...not sure if you intended that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be any set, then we can define
$$ \Sigma := X^{\mathbb{N}} =  \{a = (a_n)_{n=0}^\infty \ | \ a_n \in X\}.$$
Let $\pi_n : \Sigma \rightarrow X$ be the projection map defined by $\pi_n(a) := a_n.$ The left-shift map is the map defined by the relationship
$$S : \Sigma \rightarrow \Sigma, \ \ \pi_n \circ S = \pi_{n+1}.$$

**Exercise:** Show that the relationship gives rise to a well-defined function.
(Hint: Show that $S(a) = b$, where $b_n = a_{n+1}$. Then show that if $a = b$, then $S(a) = S(b)$.)

Notice there's nothing about linearity here, since $\Sigma$ is not even a vector space (as $X$ is arbitrary).

**Exercise:** Suppose $X = V$ for some vector space over $\mathbb{F}$. Give $\Sigma$ a vector space structure in the "obvious" way (addition is componentwise, scaling is componentwise).

1. Show that $\pi_n : \Sigma \rightarrow V$ is a linear map.
2. Show that this forces $S$ to be linear by the above relationship.

In your example, you define the sequence $a := (a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ where $a_{2n} = a_n + a_{n-1}$. When you write
$$S(a_{2n}) = S(a_n + a_{n-1}),$$
this doesn't make sense, because $a_{2n} \in X$ not in $\Sigma$.

**Edit:** I think I know what you are getting at now. Let $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty \in \Sigma$ be a fixed sequence and define $Y := (a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$. Notice this is a set of elements in the sequence. Consider
$$ T : Y \rightarrow Y, \ \ T(a_n) := a_{n+1}.$$
This would be the left-shift map on a *specific sequence.* Notice how it doesn't fit into the same framework as the usual left-shift map, so we shouldn't expect anything about the usual left-shift map to apply to this map $T$. As an easy example, think about the sequence
$$ a_n := \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } n \text{ is even}, \\ 0 \text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
In particular, in our set up we have $Y := \{0,1\}$ and the map $T$ is just given by $T(0) = 1$ and $T(1) = 0$ (alternatively: $T(x) = 1-x$). Observe $Y$ is not a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, since it's not closed under addition or scaling. In particular, it doesn't make sense to talk about $T$ being linear in this context.

If we think about it as a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, it does make sense, but it's a bit silly (and it's really restricted to just this example). Even if we modify this so that it is a vector space, $T$ fails to be linear, since
$$1 = T(0) = T(0 \cdot 0) \neq 0 \cdot T(0) = 0 \cdot 1 = 0.$$

Other observations to make:

- $T$ in the above example also arises as the left shift map of the sequence $(0,1,0,1,\ldots)$, so it's not limited to just one sequence.
- If $S(x) = x$ or $S \circ S(x) = x$, then $T$ is a well-defined map on just this sequence. However, outside of these examples, $T$ fails to be well-defined. Take the sequence $(0,0,1,0,0,1,\ldots)$. Then $Y := \{0,1\}$, and $T(0)$ could be either $0$ or $1$ (however $T(1)$ is always $0$). You can fix this by attaching an index to the points in $Y$, so instead of $Y$ you think about
  $$Y' := \{(x,n) \ | \ x \in Y, n \in \mathbb{N}, \text{ and } a_n = x),$$
  but you'll see very quickly this is not a vector space, so $T$ defined on this space still fails to be linear (and if you go this route, you'll see $T$ really depends on the sequence).

I've thought about it a bit and I don't see the advantage of studying $T$ over $S$, except that it's giving you some information about a particular sequence. Even then, I think any information you get from $T$ you could also get from studying the orbit of a sequence under $S$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "this doesn't make sense"? Why doesn't it make sense to apply $S$ to $a_{2n}$?

Comment: $S$ is defined on *sequences*, $S : \Sigma \rightarrow \Sigma$. We have that $a_{2n} \in X$ is an *element*. You could define a sequence like $(a_2, a_4, \ldots) \in \Sigma$, and then define sequences $(a_1, a_2, \ldots)$ and $(a_0, a_1, \ldots)$ and apply $S$ to those but you should be careful with how you write it. If you do this, you'll just get $S(a_2, a_4, \ldots) = (a_4, a_6, \ldots) = (a_2, a_3, \ldots) + (a_1, a_2, \ldots) = S(a_1, a_2, \ldots) + S(a_0, a_1, \ldots).$

Comment: What if I define $S$ the way I do? I mean in principle I could have $S$ increasing the index by 1, or? Could this be a proper definition of an operator (maybe not a shift operator though)?

Comment: Would my analysis above apply then, meaning this $S$ could not be a linear operator?

Comment: Btw, thanks. I also like your exercises :-) I just haven't accepted yet, because I would love an answer to my other question.

Comment: @Diger Check the edit -- does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You are being deceived by notation. $S$ is always a linear operator, on any space of sequences you like. What does that mean exactly?

$$S(a_1, a_2, a_3,  \ldots ) = (a_2, a_3, \ldots)$$

Your recurrence relation can be written as an equation in terms of sequences,

$$(a_2, a_4, a_6, \ldots) = (a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots) + (a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots)$$

You can certainly apply a shift to this equation, and it will give you the right answer, since $S(a_2, a_4, a_6, \ldots) = (a_4, a_6, \ldots)$ and so on. You just get one less equation. Your implicit claim that $S$ should just "increase the index by 1" or whatever is just not accurate. If it's not clear, imagine the sequence instead of the index.

Comment: Ok I see. Could I still define $S$ to have my property "increasing the index by 1"?

Comment: @Diger Remember what a sequence is. For example, what if the sequence is $(1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots)$. You are proposing, I think, that $S(1) = 2$, $S(2) = 3$, and so on. But then if you have a different sequence like $(1, \frac12, \frac13, \ldots)$, you have $S(1) = \frac12$. But you previously said $S(1) = 2$. So you get a contradiction much sooner - because the idea is meaningless. You might think that what I wrote is not what you mean, but I doubt that any meaning can be given to the idea you have in mind.